# c++: templates for Comparators throws an error

Tags: c++

is there anything wrong with this function prototype? I am trying to pass less as the default comparator function.

```
template<class iter, typename T, class compare>
void bubble_sort(iter first, iter last, compare cmp = less<T>)
```

the compiler throws an error saying:

```
expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
 void bubble_sort(iter first, iter last, compare cmp = less<T>)
```

Comment: `less<T>` is a type, not an object. You need `compare cmp = less<T>{}`. Also, it's always better to show a proper [mcve].

Comment: @super the error goes away, when I add {}. But, I have one more question. How do i call this function without compare argument? I mean how do I specify T during function call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`less<T>` is a type, but you need to give an object of that type as the default argument.

```
template<class iter, typename T, class compare>
void bubble_sort(iter first, iter last, compare cmp = less<T>{})
```

If you want to be able to specify T explicitly, the best way is to swap the order of your template arguments, putting `T` first.

```
template<typename T, class iter, class compare>
void bubble_sort(iter first, iter last, compare cmp = less<T>{})
```

Now you can call it and only explicitly specify `T` like so

```
bubble_sort<int>(some_container.begin(), some_container.end());
```